# How to get a specific mail's web url from it's ID retrieved from apps script?

Tags: url, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, url-parameters

**Context:**
I'm writing a webapp in GAS in order to help sales to find specific mails for GDPR.
it's a sort of mail filters, with some research templates, that returns specific mails of the user's mailbox, then he can delete it, or consult it

**Issue:**
I'm trying to find a way to open gmail onto the specific mail that is previoused on my webapp.
As I said just above, for a given mail , the user can delete it (This is ok), or open it in gmail to consult the whole thread before deletion. That's the "open" part I don't know how to work with.

Id like to use the `UrlFetchApp`, and create the URL with the mail.

I'm able to get the id of the mail, but the id isn't the same when you are on gmail. I suppose it's a mix between the id of the mail and the session token. But how may i recreate it ?

Maybe there is a function to do so I haven't find yet ?

Any clues ? :)

Comment: Have you tried using the id at the end of `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/`?

Comment: I feel stupid... Since it was different, it seemed me it wasn't even necessary to try. Because you asked i tried.... And it work! xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Kessy, i've outpassed my first impression, tried to enter
[https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/[id]](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/%5Bid%5D), and it worked (you're then redirected to the correct URL, the one i talked about, but who cares about that).

So there is no issue... The solution is to use the ID anyway.

I don't even know if this question should be deleted or not.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer in 23h. But you may delete the whole post if it seems useless to keep it.